# Arguments of \newcommand as variable names?

Tags: macros

I have the following situation: I want to use the argument of `\newcommand` to be the name of a new variable, which I define within `\newcommand` using `\def`.

When I try to compile it always says that my newly defined variable doesn't exist. I think the problem is the "#"-symbol of the argument within the `\def` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{src}
\newcommand{\src}[1]{\stepcounter{src}\def \#1 {\arabic{src}} [\arabic{src}]}
\begin{document}
\src{testone}
\src{testtwo}
first test: \testone
second test: \testtwo
\end{document}
```

My expected output would be:

1
2
first test: 1
second test: 2

But instead I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence. \testone
! Undefined control sequence. \testtwo
```

Does anyone have a solution for how to use the `#` for a variable name?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX Try `\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname ` instead of `\def \#1`. But your counter number will be wrong anyway. It will use the current counter value, so it must be expanded, e.g. `\edef`, for example

Comment: Please consider to accept one of the given answers here!

Answer (score 19):

The construction of command sequence names can be done with

`\csname #1\endcsname`

but this is not sufficient for `\def`, it must be prepended with `\expandafter`, to expand the sequence name first, then use `\def` (the same holds for `\edef` etc.)

i.e.:

`\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{some expansion stuff}`

will expand to `\def\foo{some expansion stuff}` if `#1` contains foo.

I used `\edef` here to use the counter number at the time of definition of the macro name, otherwise `\arabic{src}` would print the current number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{src}

\newcommand{\src}[1]{\stepcounter{src}\expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname {\arabic{src}} [\arabic{src}]}
\begin{document}
\src{testone}

\src{testtwo}

first test: \testone

second test: \testtwo
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks a lot! However, when executing `\src` I get a big space in front of [number]. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Of course this will not work this way if `#1` has a `\\` in it

Comment: @Philipp: Which big space? There is only the usual paragraph indentation

Comment: do you know why I can't use `\src` within the `itemize` environment?

Comment: `\begin{itemize}\item \src{foo} \foo \end{itemize}` works for me

Comment: @Philipp If you wants the definition to survive outside an environment, you need `\xdef` instead of `\edef`.

Comment: `\csdef` and friends from `etoolbox` can be used to simplify this avoiding the `\expandafter`

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Of course but I wanted to provide a package - less solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Christian Hupfer has well explained what happens. You might enjoy a different approach based on `expl3`.

The main function used is `\cs_new:cpx`, which is a variant of `\cs_new:Npn`.

1. `cs` stands for “control sequence”
2. `new` is self explaining
3. `:` separates the function name from the *signature*, that is, the list of its arguments
4. `N` stands for a single token
5. `p` stands for “parameter text” (in the example case below nothing)
6. `n` stands for “braced argument” (the replacement text)

The variant is `\cs_new:cpx` where `c` means that we expect a braced argument which will be transformed into a single symbolic token with its backslash at the beginning; `x` instead means that the corresponding argument will be fully expanded. We need full expansion because we want to store the current value of the counter, not the instructions to produce the value.

The other functions are `\int_new:N` that allocates a new variable of type `int` (integer) and `\int_gincr:N` that globally increments the variable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% allocate a new integer variable
\int_new:N \g_philipp_src_int

% the main command
\NewDocumentCommand{\src}{m}
 {
  % step the integer variable
  \int_gincr:N \g_philipp_src_int
  % define \#1 with expansion of the replacement text
  \cs_new:cpx { #1 } { \int_to_arabic:n { \g_philipp_src_int } }
  % print the current value
  [\int_to_arabic:n { \g_philipp_src_int }]
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\src{testone}
\src{testtwo}

first test: \testone

second test: \testtwo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this a little bit over the top ? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Why? It's essentially the same as yours, but with no `\expandafter` trickery. `;-)`

Comment: I know, but it might be confusing for somebody not familiar with L3 - syntax.

Comment: Arguably, L3 syntax is an easier lift than dealing with the vagaries of TeX's macro expansion system.

Comment: @DonHosek Really! No more `\expandafter`! :-)

Answer (score 4):

As an other option you can use the package [`etoolbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox?lang=de). The package provides a lot of useful commands and hooks.

In your case the command `\csdef` is useful which is defined by `etoolbox`. This is similar to the [solution of Christian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345934/5239).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{src}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\src}[1]{\stepcounter{src}\csedef{#1}{\arabic{src}}[\arabic{src}]}
\begin{document}
\src{testone}

\src{testtwo}

first test: \testone

second test: \testtwo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, but my solution does not need a package (see the comment of Andrew Swann below my answer ;-) (+1)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Sorry. I missed this. (on the other side: too many comments ;-) )

Comment: Blame the O.P. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [zref](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref) for making things available throughout the entire document—analogously to LaTeX 2ε's `\label`-`\ref`-mechanism.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveNumber@RefUndefText{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveNumber@RefUndefText{%
      \texorpdfstring{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}}{??}%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveNumber{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveNumber[1]{%
      \texorpdfstring{\zref@refused{#1}}{}%
      \zref@extractdefault{#1}{numbertostore}{\RetrieveNumber@RefUndefText}%
    }%
  }%
}{%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveNumber@RefUndefText{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveNumber@RefUndefText{%
      \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveNumber{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveNumber[1]{%
      \zref@refused{#1}%
      \zref@extractdefault{#1}{numbertostore}{\RetrieveNumber@RefUndefText}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%
\zref@newprop{numbertostore}[0]{0}%
\@ifdefinable\src{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\src[1]{%
    \stepcounter{src}%
    \begingroup
    \zref@setcurrent{numbertostore}{\arabic{src}}%
    \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{numbertostore}%
    \endgroup
    \RetrieveNumber{#1}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\newcounter{src}

\begin{document}

first test: \RetrieveNumber{testone}
second test: \RetrieveNumber{testtwo}
\src{testone}
\src{testtwo}
first test: \RetrieveNumber{testone}
second test: \RetrieveNumber{testtwo}


\end{document}
```

[image]